# PHP - Don't repeat yourself?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, design-patterns

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/seo-content-helper/tags/1.1/get-data.php

**Don't repeat yourself**

I know of the "Don't repeat yourself". Still it's getting messy in some places. The code below contains three blocks of code.

They are similar in some ways and different in others. It don't follow the same pattern in all ways.

**What it do**

It creates an array that I loop out on the frontend.

**Question**

Are there any better ways to do this kind of stuff? Less messy, better structure?

```
    $message_start = '<strong>h2 tags</strong> - ';
    $message_end = '<span class="counter">' . $this->count_h2 . '</span>';
    if( $this->count_h2 == 0 ) {
        $message = 'No tags found. Add some!';
        $array['content_editor']['count_h2']['status'] = 2;
    } elseif( $this->count_h2 == 1 ) {
        $message = 'Some found. Too few!';
        $array['content_editor']['count_h2']['status'] = 1;
    } else {
        $message = 'Many found. Great!';
        $array['content_editor']['count_h2']['status'] = 0;
    }
    $array['content_editor']['count_h2']['message'] = $message_start . $message . $message_end;
    $array['content_editor']['count_h2']['count'] = $this->count_h2;

    $message_start = '<strong>h3-h6 tags</strong> - ';
    $h2_h6 = $this->count_h3 + $this->count_h4 + $this->count_h5 + $this->count_h6;
    $counter = ( $h2_h6 == 0 ) ? '' : $h2_h6;
    $message_end = '<span class="counter">' . $counter . '</span>';
    if( $h2_h6 == 0 ) {
        $message = 'No found. Add some!';
        $array['content_editor']['count_h3_h6']['status'] = 1;
    } else {
        $message = 'Found, great!';
        $array['content_editor']['count_h3_h6']['status'] = 0;
    }
    $array['content_editor']['count_h3_h6']['message'] = $message_start . $message . $message_end;
    $array['content_editor']['count_h3_h6']['count'] = $this->h2_h6;

    $message_start = '<strong>Title keywords</strong> - ';
    $counter = ( $this->found_keywords1_post_title == 0 ) ? '' : $this->found_keywords1_post_title;
    $message_end = '<span class="counter">' . $counter . '</span>';
    if( count( $this->keywords1 ) == 0 ) {
        $message = 'No primary added.';
        $array['content_editor']['missing_keywords1_post_title']['status'] = 2;
    } elseif( $this->found_keywords1_post_title == 0 ) {
        $message = 'No primary found.';
        $array['content_editor']['missing_keywords1_post_title']['status'] = 2;
    } else {
        $s = ( $this->found_keywords1_post_title != 1 ) ? 's' : '';
        $message = 'Primary found.';
        $array['content_editor']['missing_keywords1_post_title']['status'] = 0;
    }
    $array['content_editor']['missing_keywords1_post_title']['message'] = $message_start . $message . $message_end;
    $array['content_editor']['missing_keywords1_post_title']['count'] = $this->found_keywords1_post_title;
```

Comment: I think the question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They all have common pattern. You just need to figure it out.

Comment: overall master class holding the generic structures etc and then extend that class for each specific item you're looking for may make it a little easier to follow/read

Comment: What does the `$array` variable contain except `['content_editor']`?

Comment: @exizt ['content_editor'] is one section. There are more sections than one. For the full code look at the link in the beginning of my post.

Comment: @crush Thanks for the constructive comment. ;)

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov That did not help me that much. I kind of knew that already. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a clean array and prepare the variables before. It makes it more readable.

```
$array = array(
        'content_editor' => array(
            'count_h2' => array(
                'message_start' => 'h2 tags',
                'messages' => array(
                    0 => 'Many found. Great!',
                    1 => 'Some found. Too few!',
                    2 => 'No tags found. Add some!'
                ),
                'count' => $count_h2['count']
            ),
            'count_h3' => array(
                'message_start' => 'h3-h6 tags',
                'messages' => array(
                    0 => 'Found, great!',
                    1 => 'No tags found. Add some!'
                ),
                'count' => $count_h3['count']
            ),
            'missing_keywords1_post_title' => array(
                'status' => $missing_keywords1_post_title['status'],
                'message_start' => 'Title keywords',
                'messages' => array(
                    0 => 'Primary found!',
                    2 => 'No primary found!'
                ),
                'count' => $missing_keywords1_post_title['count']
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for cleaning you code :

```
function pstrong($txt) {
    return "<strong>$txt</strong>";
} 

function pcounter($txt) {
    return '<span class="counter">' . $txt. '</span>';
}

$this->count_h1 = 1;
$this->h2_h6 = $this->count_h3 + $this->count_h4 + $this->count_h5 + $this->count_h6;
$array = array(
    'count_h2' => array(

        'title' => 'h2 tags',

        0 => array(
            'message' => 'No tags found. Add some!',
            'status' => 2
        ),

        1 => array(
            'message' => 'Some found. Too few!',
            'status' => 1
        ),

        'else' => array(
            'message' => 'Some found. Too few!',
            'status' => 0
        )
    ),

    'h2_h6' => array(
        'title' => 'h3-h6 tags',

        0 => array(
            'message' => 'No found. Add some!',
            'status' => 1
        ),


        'else' => array(
            'message' => 'Found, great!',
            'status' => 0
        )
    )
);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    $message = (!empty($value['title'][$index]) ? $value['title'][$index]['message'] : $value['title']['else']['message']);
    $array['content_editor'][$key][$index]['message'] = pstrong($value['title']) . $value['title'][$index]['message'] . pcounter($key);
    $array['content_editor'][$key][$index]['count'] = $this->$key;
}
```